# How do I handle a question mark being sent through a url?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, post, axios

I am using axios to send some strings to my database. The current things im sending are

```
1: Header -> the value can be anything such as "Who is Michael Scott?"
2: Body -> the value can be anything such as "Why do people quote Michael Scott a lot?"
```

The axios command im using is:

```
  axios.post(`/post/create/${Header}/${Body}`).then(result => {
    alert("Your post has been added!")
    console.log("Posted")
  }).catch(function (error) {
      // Output error
      console.log(error);
  });
```

The output in the url (address bar) is:

```
http://my_ip_here:3000/api/v1/post/create/Who%20is%20Michael%20Scott?/Why%20do%20people%20quote%20Michael%20Scott%20a%20lot?/
```

This ends up giving me a 404 because of the question mark.  My question is, how do I handle question marks inside strings that are passed as a url parameter?

If it helps, Im using React.js, Axios, and Mysql.

Comment: you can pass your data and retrive as query parameter as well /post/create?header='your header'&body='your body'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to URL encode them.

Before passing their value to axios, make sure you run `encodeURIComponent(myString)`.

Maybe this:

```
axios.post(`/post/create/${encodeURIComponent(Header)}/${encodeURIComponent(Body)}`).then(result => {...}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am surprised at how much I googled and not once did i see encodeURIComponent() anywhere! Thanks for the quick and short reply Bruno!

Answer (score 0):

i think if you use this url : `/post/create/${Header}/${Body}` is not best practice. 
if you use post method i suggest you to pass your data in body.

```
axios.post(`/post/create/`, {header: Header, body:Body}).then(result => {
    alert("Your post has been added!")
    console.log("Posted")
}).catch(function (error) {
    // Output error
    console.log(error);
});
```